# Ingest-by tag on data ingestion in Azure Data Explorer is getting reapply to previously ingested data

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, kql

How can I modify my data ingestion code to apply tags based on the current date and prevent duplication of ingestion per day? Currently, the code tags the data with the current date and checks for existing tags. Although it works for ingesting data and adding "ingest-by" tags, I noticed that the tag for April 12 is being reapplied to data ingested on April 11.

[image]

```
def ingest_managed_devices(self, data, database="Incidents", table="ManagedDevices"):
    tag = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    current_tags = '''
    ManagedDevices
    | extend tags = tostring(extent_tags())
    | distinct tags
    | extend item = parse_json(tags)
    | mv-expand tag = item
    | project trim_start("ingest-by:", tostring(tag))
    '''
    response = self.client_query.execute(database, current_tags)        
    tags = [i[0] for i in response.primary_results[0].raw_rows]
    for i in tags:
        if tag == i:
            return

    with open("managedDevices.tmp", "w") as file:
        for item in data:
            file.write(json.dumps(item) + "\n")
    if data:
        ingestion_props = IngestionProperties(database=database,table=table,data_format=DataFormat.MULTIJSON, ingestion_mapping_reference="ManagedDevicesMapping", ingest_if_not_exists=[tag],ingest_by_tags=[tag])
        self.client_ingest.ingest_from_file("managedDevices.tmp", ingestion_properties=ingestion_props)
    os.remove("managedDevices.tmp")
```

Comment: can you please share sample input data for `ManagedDevices`.

Comment: Hi Ritika, I removed the info but this is how it looks like.

"Items": {"id":"001da034-CCCC-CC-BBBB-AAAAAAAAA","userId":"001da034-CCCC-CC-BBBB-AAAAAAAAA","deviceName":"CDDDD","ownerType":"company","managedDeviceOwnerType":"company","managementState":"managed","enrolledDateTime":"2023-01-30T22:37:32Z","lastSyncDateTime":"2023-04-30T12:28:32Z","chassisType":"unknown","operatingSystem":"Windows","deviceType":"windowsRT","complianceState":"compliant","jailBroken":"Unknown","managementAgent":"mdm","osVersion":"10.0.20044.2728","easActivated":true,"aadRegistered":true,"azureADRegistered":true}